# Cannot expand the folder

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-2013

`Boss` wants access to all staff mailboxes (31 users).

I've added full access permissions for each mailbox via powershell:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "STAFF" -User" "BOSS" -AccessRights FullAccess
```

All mailboxes are appearing in bosses outlook. A couple of mailboxes will not expand and give the following error:

[image: Error Message Image]

> `Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously. Try closing messages you have opened or removing attachments and images from unsent messages you are composing.`

This error still appears even when no other mailboxes are expanded and it's always the same couple of mailboxes that give the error (user mailboxes).

(Outlook 2013 w/ Exchange 2013, Remote Desktop Environment, mailboxes all on same DB).

Comment: See: [Exchange Store Limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477612%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), specifically Message under Open Item Limits.

Comment: Does that link also apply to outlook/exchange '13?

Answer (score 0):

Does he need to have all of the mailboxes open at the same time?
This has huge implications for performance both for the Exchange server and the client, particularly as you are using RDP, and it isn't something I would recommend.

Furthermore, depending on your jurisdiction, your boss could be breaking the law. Being the boss, owner or whatever doesn't make it ok to look at people's mailboxes without cause in a lot of locations.

When I have had to do this in the past, against my recommendation I might add, I have not tried to have all mailboxes open at the same time. The manager is granted the permissions, and auto-mapping is disabled when doing so, therefore stopping all mailboxes from opening within Outlook. The manager can then look when required, but doesn't have the performance impact of having them all open.

Although when word gets round that he has access to everything, it will not go down well and could cause some resentment in the staff. Therefore having the mailboxes open on demand ensures that they aren't all listed if someone catches a glimpse by accident.

Simon.

Comment: It's against my recommendation also!! The staff are aware that he has access to their emails :-/ How would he access the mailboxes if auto mapping is disabled?

Comment: Have removed automapping from the affected mailboxes, re-added permissions (with automapping disabled) and manually added the mailboxes to open via "Open these additional mailboxes" option in account settings. Issue appears to be fixed!

Comment: Issue is back :-/

Comment: Doesn't surprise me - you have probably hit the throttled limits by having too many mailboxes open.

Comment: So take a look at the throttling policy then? I was thinking I'd need to, darn.

Comment: You will need to create a new throttling policy just for that one user, then apply it to the mailbox. It will not take effect immediately.

Comment: How long does it take? Is it linked to a service that can be restarted or is it closer to some form of replication?

Comment: It will be subject to the usual caching of Exchange, so a couple of hours. The only way to speed it up is to restart the information store service, which will kick everyone out of Exchange.